# Can't capture using set-literal, set(), or empty dict-literal (PEP-634, PEP-636)

Tags: python, pattern-matching, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

I work at a Python shop, and I've got the green-light to start using 3.10 (we're so cutting-edge). SMP was a little disappointing at first, as I was anticipating Rust-style matching, but it's still pretty dang awesome.

...It has some quirks... I can match empty lists as expected, but I can't match empty dict literals, and I can't match set literals at al -- I can match dicts and sets by asserting the type of a capture, but that's kind of defeating the point of SMP.

Examples below, but I can't find existing SO questions, I can't find Python issue reports, and I can't find an explanation in the body of PEP-634 or PEP-636. A pointer towards an example of any of those 3 options probably counts as an "answered question", but I'm asking because I'm hoping there are answers.

Examples:

```
# predictable and sane
match [1,2,3]:
    case [1,2,3]: print("lists are no substitute for arrays, but they do generally behave")
    case _: print("nice, predictable, and Never :)")

# a bit weird, but makes sense given the grammar
match (1,2,3):
    case tuple([1,2,3]): print("'e's a sinner, right, but 'e's friendly enough")
    case list((1,2,3)): print("This bit's fine. It sure is Python, but smells pleasantly of rust")

# this is officially annoying, but still workable. I'd rather have SMP like this than not.
match {"one": 1, "two": 2}:
    case dict(one=1, two=2): print("like, I get this not working...")
    case dict((("one", 1), ("two", 2))): print("...and I can't imagine this ever making sense.")
    case {"one": 1, "two": 2}: print("but you knew all along this was gonna work, so it's OK...")

# Definitely. Getting. Weirder:
match {1,2,3}:
    case set((1,2,3)): print("This should work, as far as what PEP-634 describes")
    case set(capture) if capture == {1,2,3}: print("There's this, sure, but...!?")
    case {1, 2, 3}: print("Syntax error. If anyone asks. '{' and '}' are for mapped captures.")
    case _: print("is there, for real, no way to capture a set-literal?")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67893188/846892

Comment: @ashwiniChaudhary, that is exactly the issue I'm describing. It has plenty of the right keywords in it, so not sure why that didn't come up earlier. Thanks!!