Can you use set literals inside Python match statement cases?
Can you use set literals in match/case statements?  I wanted to do something like this:
def describe(fruitbasket: list[str]) -> str:
    match set(fruitbasket):
        case {"Bananas"}:
            return "all bananas"
        case {"Apples", "Pears"}:
            return "all european fruit"
        case {"Apples", "Pears", "Bananas"}:
            return "every type of fruit"
        case _:
            return "a mix of fruit"

assert describe(["Apples", "Pears"]) == "all european fruit"
assert describe(["Bananas", "Bananas"]) == "all bananas"

but I get (in Python 3.12):
  File "/tmp/thing.py", line 22
    case {"Bananas"}:
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I actually wanted to use an enum and do something like case {Fruit.BANANAS}: but I'd like to understand whether it's something about sets and the match statement that I'm misunderstanding.

this is actually answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67828095/structural-pattern-matching-python-matching-a-set-frozenset
should i delete it?
